# Can MVC UpdateModel use Enterprise Library VAB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

...or should I say, what's the cleanest way to use Enterprise Library 5 VAB with MVC?

I currently use the form:

```
ActionResult Save(int id, FormCollection form)
{
   SomeModel model = somehowgetbyid(id);

   UpdateModel(model);

   somehowvalidate(model);

   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {

etc...
```

Can VAB decorated classes be validated automagically by updatemodel, or do I get the validator manually and validate it after that call?
Or are there even better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I didn't need to do anything. MVC picks up the VAB attributes by itself.
This is for Enterprise Library 5.0.

Wow!

Comment: Yep. That's because the VAB attributes inherit from the base validation attribute of DataAnnotations. MVC natively works with DataAnnotations attributes.

Comment: An observation I've made is that if there are rulesets involved, the default ruleset isn't invoked. It just makes the modelbinder skip the validation attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have nice example of creating a ModelValidatorProvider with Enterprise Library VAB (by Brad Wilson):

- http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/enterprise-library-validation-example-for-aspnet-mvc-2.html

It will allow you to use it in any way you want (implicit validation of action parameters or explicit calls to UpdateModel/TryUpdateModel)